# Linaro toolchain libstdc++.so.6 missing

Tags: buildroot, toolchain

I'm trying to run the arm linux gcc (linaro 2013 toolchain) and am getting the following error:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It's building 32 bit on a 64 bit operating system. I'm running Ubuntu Precise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to install `apt-get install lib32stdc++6`

Comment: ... But that's presumably built for `x86`, not `ARM`, so I'm surprised that would work... @ChristianStewart are you sure this solved your problem?